Knights, Knaves, and Spies
I need help understanding this problem.
An island has three kinds of inhabitants: knights, who always tell the truth, knaves, who
always lie, and spies, who can either tell the truth or lie. You encounter three people: A, B,
and C, and you know for sure that one is a knight, one is a knave, and one is a spy. Each of
the three knows the type of the other two.

A says, “I am a spy”.
B says, “I am a spy”.
C says, “B is a spy”.

What are the types of A, B, and C?
I believe A = knave, B = spy, C = Knight. What do you folks think?

Well, for a cheap remark:  neither $A$ nor $B$ can be the Knight, so....

Yeah, I think I was overthinking it a lot and I believe it wasn't that hard. Thank you

Welcome to PE. Clearly C revealed the truth about A and B .... Where did you spot the puzzle ?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

Your belief that, A = knave, B = spy, C = Knight is correct.
In knight/knave/spy puzzles, it is often best to postpone figuring out who the spy is because a spy can say anything.  In other words, a rule of thumb is to begin by trying to figure out who the knight or knave is.
Let’s begin by trying to figure out who the knight is.  Both A and B say that they are a spy.  Neither of these two can be the knight because then their statements would be lies.  So by process of elimination C is the knight.  Since C is a knight, C’s statement is true: B is a spy.  Finally, by process of elimination A is the knave.

B and C are in agreement, so either both are telling the truth (one is knight and other is spy) or both are lying (one is knave and other is spy).
If B is telling the truth: "I am a spy" true -> B is a spy, so C must be a knight and A is a knave. This means A's statement is false so A is not a spy, which is consistent.
If B is lying: "I am a spy" false -> B is not a spy, so B is a knave. So C must be a spy, and A the knight, so "I am a spy" true -> A is the spy, a contradiction.
The first case holds so A = knave, B = spy, C = knight is correct.

As others have stated, A = knave, B = spy, C = Knight is correct.

Proof using linear programming and Pyomo software within Python.

Sets:


$I = (1, 2, 3)$ where (1,2,3) represent the three given constraints
$J = (A, B, C)$ where (A,B,C) represents the three inhabitants


Decision Variables:


$X_{i} \quad \forall i \in I$, variables tracking the truth value of each constraint
$Y_{j} \quad \forall i \in J$, variables tracking the the location of our Spy


Constraints:
a. A says, “I am a spy”.
b. B says, “I am a spy”.
c. C says, “B is a spy”.

Model:


\begin{align}
  && \text{Minimize:} \quad \text{None} && \\
  \text{s.t.} && \\
  && X[1] = Y[A] \tag{a}\\ 
  && X[2] = Y[B] \tag{b}\\
  && X[3] = 1-Y[B] \tag{c}\\
  && X_{i}, Y_{j} \in \{0,1\} && \forall i \in I, \forall j \in J \tag{d}
\end{align}
Constraints (a) and (b) equate the X variable to the respective Y variable, meaning that if this statement were true, then that inhabitant would be the spy and both the X and Y values would equal 1, otherwise 0. Constraint (c) equates $X_{3}$ to the opposite of the value of $Y_{B}$, meaning either the statement is true and $X_{3} = 0, Y_{B} = 1$ or the statement is false and $X_{3} = 1, Y_{B} = 0$. Constraint (d) ensures that all these variables are binary.
Note: Because we are only searching for a solution that satisfies the given constraints, there exists no true objective function to minimize/maximize.

Solution:

$X_1 = 0, X_2 = 1, X_3 = 0$, indicating that statement 2 (B says, "I am a spy'") and statement 3 (C says, "B is a spy") are true.
$Y_A = 0, Y_B = 1, Y_C = \text{None}$, agreeing with our X variables above.
$Y_A$ = 0 so A is our Knave, $Y_B$ = 1 so B is our Spy, leaving $Y_C$ as our Knight (ignore the 'None' value for $Y_C$).

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
